# Sentence Connectors

Tags: grammaticality, participial-phrases

Is this sentence right?

> Italian is a null-subject language, subjective pronouns are usually dropped, their presence implied by verbal inflections.

Are the two clauses *Italian is a null-subject language* and *subjective pronouns are usually dropped* well connected to each other?

Comment: You mean subject pronouns. Not subjective pronouns. Null subject is not a grammatical explanation. Subject pronouns are usually dropped in Italian as the pronoun is inferred from verb endings. Also, there are not "null". They do exist: io, tu, lei etc.

Comment: 'Subjective Pronoun' is perfectly acceptable.  'Null-subject' means they can be omitted -- not that they don't exist.  It is part of the nomenclature of 'atoms' of language.

Answer (score 2):

They are not connected well -- they are connected like items in a list, but a list by itself is a sentence fragment.  Try this:

Italian is a null-subject language, **where** subjective pronouns are usually dropped, their presence implied by verbal inflection.